# Why does not Sheldon use Taxi Cabs for his Transport issues?

Tags: character, the-big-bang-theory

In some episodes of *The Big Bang Theory*, Sheldon needs a ride everywhere he wants to go because he doesn't have a driving license and he cannot drive. Also Sheldon doesn't like to go in the bus.

So my question is, why is Sheldon not using cabs? Does Pasadena town not have taxi service?

Comment: Trust issues with unknown people.

Comment: @Rahul plus germ concerns

Comment: Sheldon likes being Chauffeured around.

Comment: He's not rich, and he can get a free ride more or less whenever he wants. I'm not sure if the show addresses it more specifically.

Comment: Correction- 1) Sheldon has a driving license (revealed in S10E16) 2) Sheldon knows how to drive (he drives Penny to the hospital in S03E08)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He does use an Uber. Just go to the episode where Penny and Leonard use a Parenting book and give an option for Sheldon to either take a cab or wait an hour.

Also in season 9, when Beverly visits Penny, and all ladies (Amy, Bernadette, Beverly, and Penny) are in Penny's apartment, and Sheldon comes to apologise to Amy, he comes in a cab and mentions he does not want to repeat apologies to his cab driver Ganesh.

For the comment asking if the driver name was mentioned, here is a Youtube video of sheldon apologising to Amy and mentioning the driver name
[image]

Comment: Did he actually mentioned the driver's name as Ganesh?

Comment: @Vishwa I have added an image referring to the episode where Sheldon mention's the driver name.